# Making Raspberry Pi Windows IoT into a router?

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10, router, windowsiot

There are a number of resources explaining how to turn a Raspberry Pi into a router, for example:

http://lifehacker.com/turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-wireless-router-1582672426

http://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-router/

http://yannickloriot.com/2016/03/turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-router/

However, none of the guidelines I found were related to Windows 10 IoT on Raspberry.

Is there anyway that we could make a Raspberry Pi, running Windows 10 IoT as OS, to a router.

It could be helpful if a component (the router) can be removed in server/client applications, and can embedded in Raspberry Pi itself.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the concept of routing. If you don't intend to use your Raspberry PI to route the traffic coming from your internal LAN out to the internet and routing back from Internet to LAN, then you won't even need to make it a router in the first place. Just make this the only device facing the internet and be done with it.

Comment: However, if you are thinking of routing your LAN traffic, Windows has `Internet Connection Sharing`. `ICS` is Windows' version of routing.

Comment: As alvits points out, you can enable Internet Connection Sharing(ICS) on your windows IoT device,

Here is a nice tutorial from msdn to show you how. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/internetconnectionsharing

Comment: @alvits thanks for your response. But my question was exactly making that LAN, in a case that there is no router involved. How devices can even discover each other? I have a number of RPi devices, and would like to have one of them to act as a hub coordinating the rest. But my point is having such configuration without a router, or probably having the router functionalities embedded in a raspberry Pi.

Comment: @Jackie Thanks, please refer to my comment in response to alvits.

Comment: I am not familiar with Windows IoT. But Windows 2000 and 2003 Servers send router advertisements via Router Discovery Protocol. Here's the technet https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787292(v=ws.10).aspx. You will also need to enable router solicitations on all Windows IoT .